# Where should I place my global macros?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macros

Where should I place such debugging macros, I want to use it as gloabl.

```
#define DEBUG_MODE

#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
#define DebugLog( s, ... ) NSLog( @"<%p %@:(%d)> %@", self, [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent], __LINE__, [NSString stringWithFormat:(s), ##__VA_ARGS__] )
#else
#define DebugLog( s, ... )
#endif
```

Since prefix.pch has been removed in Xcode 6.

Comment: create a one pch file if u need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one `Constant.h` file only.

`import` `view controllers`, `macros` etc that need to be imported for `whole application`.

Use this in `viewcontroller` like this :

```
#import "Constant.h"
```

[image]

Comment: I have used a constants file before but could these not just go in the pch file?

Comment: reason to use is classification which is part of quality productivity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use macros in a Project, just add them in "Preprocessor Macro -> Debug" under "Build Settings" of your project.

And if you want to use the macros across project, you can create a Constant.h file as suggested by Prince.